# What is the relationship between the wingspan and the electrical power of the DC motor?

Tags: aircraft-design

I'm working with a cargo plane and I'm trying to find out if it's more efficient to work with more wingspan or more engine power. For example, having a variation of 300 mm (I have a model airplane), or 100 W of engine output power. How much more gain in MTOW and takeoff will I have in each case? How can I start thinking?

Comment: Working with more engine power is definitely not more efficient since you need more energy to get that power

Comment: I think you need empirical data. It may depends on too many factors, and we cannot scale aerodynamic data from airplanes to models (geometry rules forbid it to us).

Comment: Electrical implies (but not guarantees) battery power. Battery weight is a **HUGE** factor - add 100W of power but don't increase the battery size then your payload capacity and/or speed goes up but your range goes down. Increase the battery size and your payload capacity goes down. A **lot** of interacting factors.

Comment: Are you adding 300 mm to a wing that's starting at 100 mm, or is already 10 meters wide? Are you starting with 100w of power & doubling that, or with 1,000w and adding 10%? Without this most basic info, there's no conceivable way to evaluate trading off between those options. (Even then, the "everything else" involved will make realistic analysis pretty hard until far more details are given.)

Comment: You can start by showing your work.  Early aircraft with limited power favored more wing.  You'll get your weight off the ground but will be very slow in the air.  Structural strength is also important.  Very high AR wings must be strong enough.  Desired cruising speed and reserve power for climb are also important considerations.

Comment: Adding the data as a complement, I have an aircraft with a wingspan of 1.1m and I would like to know if increasing 100W (I currently have a 700W engine) of engine power would be more effective than increasing 300mm of wingspan. And if so, how is the thought/bibliography for the answer?

Comment: What is the **weight** of your aircraft?

Comment: "*I would like to know if increasing 100W of engine power would be more effective than increasing 300mm of wingspan*". More effective in terms of what? Endurance? Range? Maximum speed? Stall speed? Turn radius? Manoeuvrability? Vertical speed? ...

Comment: If you think you've got enough additional info to warrant the question being reopened, please [edit] the question and add the info there. If it's buried in the comments, odds are good that people won't see it

Answer (score 1):

Glide tests with the model in its current configuration and weight will answer a lot of questions about power required.

This depends a lot on your weight.  The heavier the aircraft, the higher its best glide speed will be.

Larger wings give a lower glide speed for a given weight.  This translates to less power required.

Smaller wings and a larger motor enable higher cruise speed.

As you already have 700W, which is almost 1 horsepower, and a 1.1 meter wingspan, you might actually be a bit *overpowered*.

As models generally fly in the 10 - 40 knot range, you can probably add more wing.  Slower flight and landings will be easier to control as well.

One other thing to consider regarding lifting efficiency, especially on this scale, is Reynolds number.  Lift/Drag ratios greatly increase when Reynolds number reach higher values.  This is accomplished by increasing speed.

> Reynolds number = Velocity m/s × chord m/(1.46 × 10$^-5$ m$^2$/s)

The effects of Reynolds number on your wing efficiency can be found at [airfoiltools.com](http://www.airfoiltools.com).

Answer (score 0):

Lengthening wings to increase the aspect ratio (AR) is usually the better way to go if you want to increase efficiency, but you need to make sure that you're using something well-designed to support the wing.

Things to consider while designing wings is to watch out for flutter, and to make sure it doesn't flex too much. You should also be considering the shape and airfoil of the wing itself. This will increase efficiency further.

I'd caution against the motor because it doesn't increase efficiency, while increasing weight and battery draw.

For